# List to Array adapter

Tags: android, arrays, adapter

This is my query in my `DatabaseHelper`

```
public List<String> getallstatus(){
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        String query  = "select * from ref_status";
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor  = db.rawQuery(query,null);
        try{
            if(cursor.moveToFirst()){

                do{
                    list.add(cursor.getString(0));
                    list.add(cursor.getString(1));

                }while(cursor.moveToNext());

            }

            cursor.close();
            db.close();


        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("onins" , e.getMessage(),e);

        }
        return list;
    }
```

This is my dataProvider class

```
public class DataProvider {

    private String regcode, regname;

    public DataProvider(String regcode, String regname){
        this.regcode =regcode;
        this.regname = regname;
    }

    public String getRegcode(){ return regcode;  }

    public void setRegCode(){ this.regcode = regcode; }

    public String getRegname(){ return regname;  }

    public void setRegname() { this.regname = regname; }


    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return regname;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if(obj instanceof DataProvider){
            DataProvider c = (DataProvider ) obj;
            if(c.getRegname().equals(regname) && c.getRegcode()==regcode ) 
              return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

and this is my `onCreate` in my main activity

```
        db = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
        List<String> result = db.getallstatus();

        //spinner elements
        ArrayList<DataProvider> datalist = new ArrayList<>();


        ArrayAdapter<DataProvider> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<DataProvider>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,datalist);
        // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
       // adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        //attaching adapter to spinner
        valueofspin.setAdapter(adapter);
       // valueofspin.setSelection(adapter.getPosition(myItem));
```

I just wanna pass the result of this List result to my array adapter. I'm new in android studio hope somebody can help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to end up with a `List` of `DataProvider`, why are you creating a `List` of `String` in `getallstatus()`? Why don't you just create a `List` of `DataProvider` there?

Comment: You have your list in result. What is dataprovider class for?

Comment: i set data provider so that i will show on the spinner just the regname and if the button triggered i will save its id but after i call the method to query i dont know how to pass the result into getter and setter

Answer (score 0):

Do this Create a constructor in your Arrayadapter

```
  public class ArrayAdapter extends....{
  ArrayList<DataProvider> dataList;
  List<String> list;
  ArrayAdapter(Context context,resources id,ArrayList<DataProvider> 
  dataList,List<String> list){
  this.context=context;
  this.dataList = datalist;
  this.list = list
}
}
```

On your Activity...Do this

```
    ArrayAdapter<DataProvider> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<DataProvider>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,datalist,result);
```

Pass result through constructor..